# ::-webkit-scrollbar makes white bar on right side

Tags: html, css

When not using `::-webkit-scrollbar` it looks fine:
[Normal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFuT0.png)

But when using `::-webkit-scrollbar` with the current code below, it gives me a white bar on the right side:

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 9px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #6495ED; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #208B97; 
}
```

This is how it looks like:
[Image with white bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caCof.png)

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? ::-webkit-scrollbar is applying your given styles.

Comment: @Akash As written in the question, when using the webkit scrollbar, it gives me a white bar on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The color for the bar is set in `-track`:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   background: #f1f1f1; 
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
}
```

You may need to add a vendor prefix for `box-shadow` too:

```
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
```

Change the background color of the track:

```
background: red;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of my awesomeness, I managed to fix this all by myself, without any help.

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to `body {}` fixed the issue.